# Confusion about typeof

Tags: javascript, operators, typeof

What is the use of the `typeof` function?

Comment: `typeof` is actually an operator, not a JavaScript function.

Answer (score 16):

`typeof` is actually an operator, not a function, it returns you the *type* of the supplied operand, and returns you always<sup>[1]</sup> a string value, that can be:

- `"undefined"`
- `"object"`
- `"boolean"`
- `"number"`
- `"string"`
- `"function"`

It can *look* like a function, because it can be applied to parenthesised expressions, but the parentheses are not mandatory, you can use it without them:

```
typeof expression
```

Is worth mentioning that you can reference even an identifier that is not declared (an unresolvable reference, e.g. a variable never declared) and it will not throw a `ReferenceError`, it will simply produce `"undefined"`, for example:

```
if (typeof imUndeclared == 'undefined') {
  // Ok...
}

// Vs.

if (imUndeclared === undefined) { // ReferenceError!
}
```

A case that can cause confusion to newcomers to the language is that the `typeof` operator returns `"object"` for a `null` value, you should keep that in mind...

Also if you want to distinguish between `Array` objects, `RegExp` objects, `Date` objects, etc, it isn't too useful, but there are other ways to accomplish it.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> With the infamous exception of JScript (IE) :), which can actually return `"unknown"`!!! for some *host objects*, e.g. `typeof new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP").abort; // "unknown"`

Answer (score 6):

## The `typeof` Operator

`typeof` is a an **unary operator** (and NOT a function), defined by the [ECMAScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript) standard and therefore implemented by most existing [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) implementations; though historically speaking, it was part of JavaScript since its version 1.1, before its ownership was handed over to ECMA International.

It is used to introspect the type of a variable by querying it (`typeof expression`) and checking the return value, which is a `string` object indicating the type with **lossy precision** (see below).

## Usage

As per the ECMAScript 5 Standard ([ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf), p. 71), it will return the following string values when tested with these given parameters of the following types:

- `Undefined` --> *"undefined"*
- `Null` --> *"object"*
- `Boolean` --> *"boolean"*
- `Number` --> *"number"*
- `String` --> *"string"*
- `Object` --> it depends:

  - native and does not implement `Call` --> *"object"*
  - native and does implement `Call` --> *"function"*
  - host and does not implement `Call` --> Implementation-defined **except may not be** *"undefined"*, *"boolean"*, *"number"*, or *"string"*

For most implementations, `typeof` will also return:

- `Array` --> *"object"*
- `Function` --> *"object"* (see above `Object`'s 2nd and 3rd case...)

*(Note that types are capitalized, whereas their string identifiers as returned by `typeof` are **not**)*

### Caveats

- As mentioned above, the type detection with `typeof` is **lossy**.
- `typeof`, as of [ECMAScript 5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#ECMAScript.2C_5th_Edition), still doesn't support `Array` (which is identified as *"object"* in most cases. (see [Douglas Crockford](http://www.crockford.com/)'s [Remedial JavaScript](http://javascript.crockford.com/remedial.html))
- Detection of `Function` and `Array` varies.

## Additional References

- [Wikipedia's ECMAScript Syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript_syntax#Variables) page will also provide usage examples of `typeof`.
- [Mozilla's Developer Center's JavaScript Reference for typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/typeof_Operator)

Comment: There is a function, `dltypeof()` that addresses most of these issues: http://www.webreference.com/dhtml/column68/ Note that an additional check for the presence of push is required near the end to catch arrays that weren't constructed with `new Array()`.

Comment: @Stan Rogers: well, first browser I tried (Google Chrome 6) doesn't support it, so I wouldn't advise to use that. For array detection, Dojo's `isArray()` and `isArrayLike()` is good enough for me, if I'm in an environment where using a lib is an option. Otherwise, just rolling out your own implementation is fine.

Comment: @Stan Rogers: OK I assume you were mentioning an addition to the JS spec, but I noticed it's just a library, apparently. Then in that case I guess it's up to you, but I'd stick to the standard and a more full-blown framework if I need that, and use dltypeof.js only if I need a similar functionality in a small script.

Comment: Odd -- it works in my copies of Chrome 6 (and Firefox, Safari, Opera and IE 6, 7 and 8) across five machines. And I've yet to find a project that warranted the Dojo tax (or jQuery) -- I consider it a major failure if an entire page with all resources is that heavy. But I have to deal with remote dialup and satellite (the Great White North is still pretty empty in a lot of places).

Comment: @Stan Rogers: actually I'm on Chrome 7.0.517.24 beta, but still. Doesn't work either for FF 3.6. Maybe you're just trying it on a page that embeds it? Sure, Dojo or jQuery is way overkill if it's just for that, but for the type of enterprise software I've been working on, using Dojo is justified and then it comes with that sort of convenience functions. Otherwise, like I said, re-implementing it or including dltypeof.js would make sense.

Comment: @Stan Rogers: I'm a bit surprised that you would seem to think this `dltypeof` function is getting any sort of wide acceptance though. I find only one relevant link online, and only a few valid reference in Google Code Search (http://google.com/codesearch?as_q=dltypeof&as_lang=javascript)

Comment: @Stan Rogers: Just realized... when I said the browsers don't support it, I meant that it's not included by default, of course. Not that it doesn't work if you include the function manually.

Comment: @Haylem: I probably should have been more clear about that. And the dltypeof() function did kind of lose out to jQuery, Dojo, Prototype/Scriptaculous and mootools. Timing, really -- thay all originated around the same time. Too bad, really, since it would have brought those libraries down in size. My largest standard library (minified) is roughly 10KB, but also reimplements most of Lotus Domino's Formula Language in JS (it just makes it easier to keep browser-side and server-side/Notes client code in sync). dltypeof is a big part of what keeps it small.

Answer (score 1):

The [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/typeof_Operator) operator returns a string indicating the type of the operand.

Answer (score 1):

Some people have suggested nice typeOf functions.  One that I recently read up on and tested thoroughly was from Chris' blog found [here](http://gotochriswest.com/blog/2012/09/21/javascript-yet-a-better-typeof-function/).  What I like about his solution is that it will always work for any native JavaScript object.  If you supply just the object, it will tell you the type of it as expected:

```
alert(typeOf([1,2,3]));  // Array
alert(typeOf(123));  // Number
alert(typeOf(/a_reg_exp/gi));  // RegExp
alert(typeOf(null));  // null
alert(typeOf(undefined));  // undefined
```

If the second parameter is a string that may identify the type, the equality between type of the object and the specified type name will be returned as a boolean:

```
alert(typeOf([1,2,3], "Array"));  // true
alert(typeOf(123, "String"));  // false
alert(typeOf(/a_reg_exp/gi, "RegExp"));  // true
alert(typeOf(null, "undefined"));  // false
alert(typeOf(undefined, "undefined"));  // true
```

Answer (score 0):

To check variable type(whether it is array, object, function etc.).